# Java DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding encrypted value are not same

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, java-8, 3des

I am trying to encrypt same data in Java using DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding algorithm with hardcoded secret key. I verifed my encrypted value using [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp). If i used secret key with special characters then Java and [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp) encrypted value are not identical.

If i used Key **2b7e151628aed2a6abf71589** and input text **1234** then encrypted result is same with [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp). Encrypted result for this text using Java is **SRC/0ptoT78=** which is same with [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp), Image is also attached for reference [image: Result]

but If i used Key **/£½ZBÝy‚÷Í( Ó—&*Ænù­;‘³** and again input text **1234** then encrypted result is not same with [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp). Encrypted result for this text using Java is **UUoh48bB9dM=** which is not same with [online tool](https://8gwifi.org/CipherFunctions.jsp), Image is also attached for reference [image: Result]

My java code is as below

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import java.security.Key;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(encrypt("/£½ZBÝy‚÷Í( Ó—&*Ænù­;‘³", "1234"));

             System.out.println(encrypt("2b7e151628aed2a6abf71589", "1234"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String key, String str) throws Exception {



        DESKeySpec desKeySpec = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));
         System.out.println(new String(key.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        Key secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(desKeySpec);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);


        byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(str.getBytes("utf-8"));

        byte[] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(bytes);
        return new String(base64Bytes);
    }


    public static String decrypt(String key, String str) throws Exception {
        byte[] data =Base64.decodeBase64(str);
        DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes());
        SecretKeyFactory keyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        Key secretKey = keyFactory.generateSecret(dks);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(data);
        return new String(decryptedBytes, "gb2312");
    }
}
```

Comment: DES uses binary keys, not passwords in text format. You should provide your keys in binary form like a byte array or a hex encoded string. The online tool don't allow you to correctly provide a binary DES keys making the tool kind of useless for DES.

Comment: Besides that it makes more sense to test against test vectors instead of frickin' awful websites.

Answer (score 0):

This is very likely a conflict between your local default encoding and the website's default encoding.

To solve it, specify an encoding when you extract the bytes of your key:

```
import static java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
...
DESKeySpec dks = new DESKeySpec(key.getBytes(UTF_8))
```

Also, you specify a non-standard encoding, `gb2312`. Try using UTF-8, UTF-16 or friends instead.

```
return new String(decryptedBytes, UTF_8);
```

If it still doesn't work, try using the other values available in `StandardCharsets` (see [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)).

Comment: i tried each encoding mention in java doc but still the result are not same when use this key
/£½ZBÝy‚÷Í( Ó—&*Ænù­;‘³

Comment: DES is obsolete and ECB mode is dangerous because it leaks data. You *really* need to use something better, like AES-GCM.

Comment: I know DES is obsolete but we have to used it because we are consuming 3rd party api in which they required DES encryption